# How do I go from modules to PCB?

Tags: arduino-uno, pcb-design

For my engineering class, I am designing a digital scale.  I have already made a working proof-of-concept by using jumper wires to connect several arduino modules to an Arduino UNO.

I want to make a PCB to simplify the design, and not just have a mess of arduino modules.  I want the design to be flat and small, so I need to make a custom PCB, integrating each module onto the board.  Say I'm not using a protoboard, but sending it to a company to get it custom manufactured.  This PCB would use through-hole components, and not SMD.

I am trying to build the eagle files for the PCB.  I have rounded up the SCH file for each arduino module, and the arduino itself.

I am trying to make this PCB in the easiest and fastest way possible.

Should I just copy and paste, and connect the modules' SCH files into one big SCH file?  Then create a BRD file to create the proper footprints and holes?

Thanks

Comment: You can probably start by removing all the stuff you don't need: pin headers, the ATmega16U2 (if you can use an ISP), the 3.3V regulator (if you use 5V logic), ...

Comment: Yes, avoid copy-pasting everything, since there are a lot of unnecessary components. See what you need from the original schematics, then insert them and, in the end, make the BRD. And... Personally I prefer SMD components (down to a 1mm pitch is easy to hand-solder them, and with a bit of manual skills and flux you can go down to 0.5mm pitch with common tools)

Comment: That's a great way to start. But it would be a good idea to try and understand what all the different components are doing. Also look at the layout of the originals. For example, you can see that the crystal for the ATMega is pretty close to the chip itself. Also sprinkle some extra capacitor footprints. If you get some intermittent problems adding some bypass capacitors can often fix things.